# Get object as (object, object) tuple method does not work

Tags: c#, oop

I have the following code:

```
public static (object, object) GetAsTuple(this object obj)
{
    if (obj is Tuple<object, object> tuple)
    {
        object item1 = tuple.Item1;
        object item2 = tuple.Item2;
        // Use item1 and item2 as needed

        return (item1, item2);
    }
    else if (obj is ValueTuple<object, object> valueTuple)
    {
        object item1 = valueTuple.Item1;
        object item2 = valueTuple.Item2;
        // Use item1 and item2 as needed

        return (item1, item2);
    }
    throw new Exception("Is not a tuple or value tuple.");
}
```

which is not correctly returning an arbitrary `object` as an `(object, object)` whenever possible. See this failed case:

[image]

Why is this failing? What would be the best practice here?

Comment: It is likely a `Tuple<int, int>` not `Tuple<object, object>`

Comment: The linked question provides an explanation of why this doesn't work but not how to fix it.